# How do I make my form process data and output in another page?

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I'm trying to make a molecular mass calculator webpage, where a user inputs a chemical formula and gets the mass as a result. I've made this work in python using raw_input(), but now I'd need to use a form with django.

I have the html form set up, but when I click "submit", the page just shows itself again.
What I want to happen is:

1. User inputs formula in form on index.html(ex. H2)
2. Form data is processed using the code that I put in the result view
3. Result is outputted in result.html

However, I'm not sure how to do this, as I've looked through the tutorial and form docs.

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render from django.db import connection from django.http
import HttpResponseRedirect from django.core.urlresolvers
import reverse import sys, re

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('MolecularMass:result'))
else:
    return render(request, 'MolecularMass/index.html')
def result(request):
    c = connections['default'].cursor()

def FindEndParentheses(separated):
    count = 0
    for index, val in enumerate(separated):
        if val == ')':
            count -= 1
            if count == 0:
                return index
        elif val == '(':
            count += 1
    raise NameError('Please close the parentheses')
def GetAtomicMass(val):
    c.execute("SELECT Atomic_Weight FROM Elements WHERE Atomic_Numer=%s" % val)
    return c.fetchone[0]
def Parser(separated, total):
    if len(separated) == 0:
        return sum(total)
    val = separated[0]
    if val == '(':
        end = FindEndParentheses(separated)
        total.append(Parser(separated[1:end], []))
        return Parser(separated[end + 1:], total)
    elif val.isdigit():
        total[-1] *= int(val)
    else:
        total.append(GetAtomicMass(val))
    return Parser(separated[1:], total)
def CalcMolecularMass(formula):
    separated = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*|\d+|\(|\)', formula)
    return('The molecular mass of {} is {:.3f}\n'.format(formula, Parser(separated, [])))
return render(request, 'MolecularMass/result.html', CalcMolecularMass(formula))
```

My index.html:

```
<h1>Enter a chemical formula to get its molecular mass</h1>
<form action="{% url 'MolecularMass:result' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="formula"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

My result.html:

```
{{ content }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this. The simplest way I can think of is to define an onclick event listener for your submit button on your index.html template that calls some javascript function that is responsible for triggering a view. Send your form data as an argument after serializing it. You should then be able to manipulate the data and use `return render(request, 'your_app/result_url', context)` The context argument is optional.

There's a few practices that the Django docs ask you to follow such as having your forms (where you're trying to input your data) in a forms.py file. This makes everything a lot easier to debug.

I would strongly recommend properly reading [Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Once you do this and things become clear to you. Look at Dajax and Dajaxice. These make asynchronous calls within the app really easy. For example dajax.assign() method allows you to manipulate HTML elements and their attributes from your views and just return json objects that would make things super simple in your use case.